# delegate textfield and restrain it only to input numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

I´m creating some `UITextField`s programmatically, and when I try to delegate them I receive this warning:

> NAVPlanViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type `id<UITextFieldDelegate>`

```
textHeight = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 160, 40)];
[textHeight setDelegate:self];
```

and in `.c` of my class I have added `@interface NAVPlanViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`.
Also, I need to restrain text field to accept only numbers, I thought to do it with this code but since `UITextField` wont `Delegate` I was not able to check it:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
                    replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (!string.length) {
            return YES;
    }

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] 
                                         invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound){
        //do something;
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: please check your delegate you want to use UITextField replace <UITextViewDelegate> into <UITextFieldDelegate>....@interface NAVPlanViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `NAVPlanViewController` interface definition, `<UITextViewDelegate>` should be `<UITextFieldDelegate>`.

Comment: Yep, i was exhausted and totally overviewed that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the delegate?

Answer (score 1):

@neilco is right conform to  like

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
{

}
@end
```

And to except only numbers, set the keyboardType to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad like

```
UITextField *age = [UITextField autolayoutView];
age.placeholder = kPlaceholderToEnterAge;
age.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
age.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
age.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
age.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
age.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
age.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: That doesn't work on ipad because it doesn't have number pad, and also pasting characters(not numbers) is possible.